# C++ debugging using VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I am new to C++, and my question might be a bit stupid.

I got a big program which was written in C++. The developer built the program in VS 2013, but I only have VS 2012 on my computer. So, I changed the platform toolset from V120 to V110, and changed the ToolsVersion="12.0" to ToolsVersion="4.0". I also have .NET framework 4.5.1, 4.5 installed on my computer. My computer system is windows 7 64 bit.

Then I can successfully build the program. But when I ran it from the debug folder, and loaded my data, I got the error:

"Debug Assertion Failed.
Program:C:\windows\system32\mfc110d.dll
File:h:\envision\src_6696\envdoc.cpp
Line 1633."

I click debug and can find that there is an assertion error:

catch( ... )
      {
      CString msg = "Error thrown during Init() when initializing the ";
      msg += name;
      msg += " plugin.";
      Report::ErrorMsg(msg);
      ASSERT(0); 
      }

But it is almost impossible for me to figure out where the error is originated from.

So, I have many my specific questions:

1. What is the possible problem for this?
2. Do I have to use VS 2013 to solve the problem?
3. Is it because of the mfc110d.dll or the .netramwork?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Jim

Comment: When that assetion fires and you break into your debugger, goto the debug menu, select debug windows... and choose "Call stack". It will tell you where you are, and show you how you got there. The *switch* of MFC shouldn't be a problem, so long as you aren't trying to ***mix*** MFC's across library boundaries.

Comment: Visual Studio can catch exception on the place where it is thrown. Go to menu Debug > Exceptions and select "C++ exceptions" and maybe also "Win32 exceptions".

Comment: Thanks. I find "Call stack". It is pretty complicated actually. The program is still under development. If the source code has bugs, then I can wait for another version.

Comment: Thanks, WhozCraig and Dialecticus. WhozCraig, Could you please explain a bit more how I can "mix" MFCs across library boundaries?

Comment: There is no way to mix modules that have different MFC Versions if they have no POD Interfaces and if the allocate and free Memory accross the modules. Only if the modules are Standard DLLs and have plain and simple interfaces you can easily mix them.